# could i re-initilize the sklearn library

Tags: python, scikit-learn

http://screencloud.net/v/cPBi

I had problem in importing the sklearn neighbors library (called "LSHForest").

the online example [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.LSHForest.html) did exactly the same I did when importing the LSHForest, but mine is not working :(

Not really sure what is possibility wrong. do I have to reinstall ubuntu (because i heared that reinstall python under ubuntu environment is not recommended)

thanks for all the great help

Comment: which version of scikit-learn do you have? LSHForest was added in 0.16: http://scikit-learn.org/dev/whats_new.html#changes-0-16

Comment: thanks do u know how to find out the version info? sorry i mean what command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You most likely have an older version of scikit-learn. You can check the current version using:

```
python -c "import sklearn as sk; print sk.__version__"
```

If you're using 0.16.1, you should be able to import LSHForest.